# Firebase Analytics - Custom Events

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to create a custom events like you can do for a website with google tag manager but for Android or iOS Apps that use the analytics dashboard from Firebase?
And if there is a way to connect Firebase analytics with google tag manager So i can measure interactions injecting code in a custom script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send custom events in Firebase Analytics, see this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events).

There is a way to use Firebase Analytics with Google Tag Manager. The main use case is that you can **intercept** the custom events above and either block them or modify them before they get sent to Firebase. Optionally, you can also forward the above Firebase custom events to Google Analytics.

It's not possible to write custom scripts in Google Tag Manager for apps like we do for the web. The main reason for this is because there is no unified scripting language (like JavaScript) in the app world.

Comment: Perfect, but if im developing an app with a JS framework and compile it for iOS and Android with Cordova , can i still use Firebase Analytics?

Comment: In that case you would need to use a 3rd party library. Did some quick searching and found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics)